# Prove that the following group of vectors is linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra

{v1...vn} are a group of independent vectors in linear space V. 
w∈V and w∉ Span(v1...vn)

I need to prove that {v1+w, v2+w, .... vn+w} is linearly independent.

I know that w is linearly independent of {v1...vn} because  w∉ Span(v1...vn).
Also, from what I understand,  if you add two groups that are linearly independent you get a linearly independent group. I think this leads somehow to the conclusion that {v1+w, v2+w, .... vn+w} is linearly independent, but I'm not sure, and even if it does I guess in order to prove it you need to do much more.

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you know about determinants?

Comment: Yes I know about determinants

Comment: Better to say "a set of independent" rather then "a group of independent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose
$$
a_1(v_1+w)+a_2(v_2+w)+\ldots+a_n(v_n+w)=0
$$
Then also 
$$
a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots+a_nv_n + a_{n+1}w=0
$$
where we set $a_{n+1}=\sum a_i$. But then we get
$$
w = \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}\left(a_1v_1+\ldots+a_nv_n\right),
$$
so $w$ is in the span of $\{v_i \}$. This is a contradiction! So either $a_{n+1}=0$ or all the $a_i=0$.

What happens in each of these two cases?

Comment: In either case this suits the definition of linear independence, right? If the only combination is one where (a1...an) are all zeros, then we get the group is linearly independent. Am I correct?

Comment: @EranDavid Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Your explanation helped me understand how to solve a few more questions, thanks!